# An unhandled exception occurred: Unexpected value 'HeaderModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, typescript, build, node-modules, angular-library

I have a strange issue.
I make different libraries for my project and each library is a widget of my application. All widgets as the same header with a title and some button.
So I create another library named header that is imported by each widgets.
Assume I have widget1 and widget2.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HeaderComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ....
  ],
  exports: [HeaderComponent]
})
export class HeaderModule { }
```

And in the public-api.ts I exports HeaderComponent and HeaderModule like that:

```
export * from './lib/header.component';
export * from './lib/header.module';
```

After I build and install my Header library correctly I import the module in widget 1 module like that.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HeaderModule } from 'header';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [Widget1Component],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HeaderModule
    ....
  ],
  exports: [Widget1Component]
})
export class Widget1Module { }
```

And this goes well, widget1 import header and its building not shows error.
When I import header in widget2 in the same way I obtain this error.

```
ERROR: Unexpected value 'HeaderModule in .../dist/header/lib/header.module.d.ts' imported by the module 'Widget2 in .../angular-proj-lib/projects/widget1/src/lib/widget1.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

An unhandled exception occurred: Unexpected value 'HeaderModule in .../dist/header/lib/header.module.d.ts' imported by the module 'Widget2 in .../angular-proj-lib/projects/widget1/src/lib/widget1.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

See "...\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-IXlNtE\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I don't understand because in all other widget (3,4,5...) that I imported HeaderModule there are no problems! I check if there are differences between widget2 and all other widgets in the tsconfig.lib.json and in the peerDependencies of the package.json but nothing strange.

Sorry if I can't provide more code but I'm not very confident with libraries.

Comment: Where is the code of **Widget2Module**?

Comment: Is the same of Widget2Module. Change only Widget1 with Widget2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my issue checking enableIvy setting of all widget and header.
All must have 'enableIvy': false; to compile correctly and work fine.